# my iPod touch was stolen and needs locating

Tags: ipod-touch

somebody stole my iPod touch 5th gen and is to be found nowhere. to my knowledge "find my iPod" in on but is not connected to wifi since the thief does not know my password and can't get in to access wifi and everything else. so is there still someway to locate my iPod and get it back?

Answer (score 1):

You can't locate the iPod unless it has some way of telling its location to you. This is almost always through Wi-Fi.

**If there's no network connection, you can't locate it, and there's no way round that.**

Comment: is there a way to track activity and stuff being done on my iPod even though it's not with me?

Comment: @Jade Only if it has a network connection.

Comment: @Jade: If the thief doesn't have the password to get in, how are you going to track activity if wifi is not turned on?